# Mercurial: rename then create new file with old name

Tags: mercurial, replace, rename

I'm using TortoiseHg.  I have a file A.  I used the rename tool to rename this to B.  All seems well.  Now I want to create a new file named A.  When I create a file with that name and go to add it to the repo, it's showing me a diff of my new file with the old A (which is now renamed to B.)

How can I rename A to B and be able to add a new A which is, y'know, new, and not have Hg think I'm modifying the old, now-nonexistent A?

Edit: In fact what I originally did was the right thing, I just wasn't committing the rename properly.  (I had committed, but only committed the newly-renamed file, and not the now-nonexistent old file.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to commit after the rename and then create the new file with same name.

```
$ hg mv A B
$ hg commit -m "moving A→B"
$ touch A
$ hg add A
$ hg commit -m "adding new A"
```

Comment: That's what I did, except that I didn't do it by entering those commands, I did it by choosing "rename" from the TortoiseHG context menu and then choosing "commit" from that menu.  It seems that this does a "copy" behind the scenes.  I'm not well versed in the details of Hg (or VCS), but I've read that there are issues with maintaing file history when renaming.  If I do what you describe, will it retain the version history of A, under the new name B, and also allow me to create the new file A with a clean slate?  Thanks.

Comment: `$ hg log --follow B` will show you the entire history of file before rename

Comment: `$ hg mv ...` is implemented as copy-and-remove

Comment: Hmmm, okay, thanks.  I hate to sound like a doofus here, but I'm not really interested in how things are implemented, nor in various extra ways of getting extra information (like hg log --follow B).  I'm interested in whether there is a series of operations I can do with the TortoiseHg menu interface, that will result in having a file named B with the history of the file that used to be called A, and having a new file A with no history (i.e., newly added to the repo.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Brendan B. Barnwell: Indeed it is possible, see my answer.

Comment: This breaks the atomicity of a commit though.. This is logically a single operation. Can we merge the commit later or something?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you the file `a.txt` in your repository. To rename it to `b.txt` and add a different file named `a.txt`, using TortoiseHg 2.x, do the following:

1. Right-click `a.txt`. In the context menu, click **TortoiseHg** > **Rename File**.
2. In the **Rename** dialog box, enter `b.txt` into the **Destination** text box. Click **Rename**.
3. Right-click the repository folder. In the context menu, click **Hg Commit**.
4. In the **Commit** window, make that you have two files checked, added `b.txt` and removed `a.txt`. Enter the commit description, and click **Commit**. Close the **Commit** window.
5. Create new file named `a.txt`. Right-click it. In the context menu, click **TortoiseHg** > **Add Files**.
6. In the **Add** window, make sure that `a.txt` is checked. Click **Add**.
7. Right-click the repository folder. In the context menu, click **Hg Commit**.
8. In the **Commit** window, make that you have `a.txt` checked. Enter the commit description, and click **Commit**. Close the **Commit** window.

Now you have a different `a.txt`, with a fresh history, and `b.txt` which remembers it used to be named `a.txt`.

**P.S.** This is exactly the same steps as Vaibhav Bajpai posted in his answer. You may have a hard time if you have problems dealing with steps expressed as `hg` commands.